# Evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}\{(\sin x)^{\cos x} + (\cos x) ^{\sin x}\}$ with logarithmic differentiation

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Spivak asks us to evaluate $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\{(\sin x)^{\cos x} + (\cos x) ^{\sin x}\}$$ by logarithmic differentiation. Does he mean for us to evaluate each term separately (which seems to turn out to be cumbersome), or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You mean evaluate the derivative?

Comment: A logarithmic derivative sometimes (usually?) means $$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \log_{\Delta x}\left(\frac{f(x + \Delta x)}{f(x)}\right)$$ the inverse of the geometric integral.

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln f(x)=\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$

Comment: I do not see what Spivak means by $evaluate$ in the case of this problem. Is it $evaluate$ $the$ $derivative$ $of$  $(\sin x)^{\cos x} + (\cos x) ^{\sin x}$ ? If this is the case, I suggest you modify the title of the post.

Comment: Where in Spivak is this exercse?

Comment: @DonAntonio It's in the log/exp chapter, 4th edition

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It was a typo, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Take $f(x)=(\sin x)^{\cos x}$. You try to differentiate $f(x)+f(\pi/2 -x)$. Use logarithmic differentiation to derivative $f(x)$.

Comment: Nice!------------

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = u+v$ where $u = (\sin x)^{\cos x}$ and $v = (\cos x)^{\sin x}$

As we know, If $f(x) = u+v, f'(x) = \dfrac{du}{dx} + \dfrac{dv}{dx}$

Consider $u = (\sin x)^{\cos x}$

$\ln u = \cos x \ln(\sin x)$

Differentiating, $\dfrac{1}{u}\dfrac{du}{dx} = \cos x \dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x} - \sin x \ln(\sin x)$ --- (A). by product rule

Now do similarly for $\dfrac{dv}{dx}$ and find $\dfrac{du}{dx}+\dfrac{dv}{dx} = f'(x)$

Edit: You will have to multiply (A) by $u$ to get $\dfrac{du}{dx}$